# Site that replaces all words on external page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, xss

I want to make something like this:
http://www.degraeve.com/translator.php
where you can input an address and then show the page with all the words replaced with something of my choosing.

First I tried to do this with simple iframes and jquery, but quickly discovered that it didn't work because of cross-site scripting.

Then I tried with ajax, which broke the image links, but is it supposed to work somehow?

I'm a novice at php so I'd greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction here!
Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, will remember that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from accessing other domains. What they do is [read the page with PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#example-2303) and than spit out the translation.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the contents of the page of interest and replace the text that is not within an HTML tag, comment, or doctype declaration and the output the resulting HTML.